# Google Maps custom objects

Tags: javascript, google-maps, object

I am working with Google Maps and trying to cache the return value to an XML document for later use. I noticed with Google Maps the Objects it returns are different? Can someone let me know what this is??

Here is the Google Map Object:

```
geometry: Object
bounds: Le        // Le?
  Z: Ke           // Ke?
    b: 49.00541699999999
    d: 49.0443675
    __proto__: Ke
  fa: Ge          // Ge?
  __proto__: Le
location: Q       // Q?
location_type: "APPROXIMATE"
viewport: Le      // Le?
```

If I try to replicate it in an object, all I get are the standard types (Object, Array, Function). How do you create custom objects like that?

Comment: Are you familiar with constructors, like `new Date()` and so on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Le`, `Ke`, `Q` and `Ge` are constructors.

- `viewport`, `bounds` and its prototype are instances of the `Le` constructor
- `Z` and its prototype are instances of the `Ke` constructor
- `fa` is an instance of the `Ge` constructor
- `location` is an instance of the `Q` constructor

Constructors are merely functions that are invoked using the `new` keyword to create instances:

```
function myConstructor(){
  this.name = 'foo';
}

var instanceOfMyConstructor = new myConstructor();

instanceOfMyConstructor.name; //foo
```

If you are going to save it to XML, you could save the name of the constructor along with the data. However, the challenge would be recreating the objects. The constructors might be internal-only functions that cannot be accessed outside the API. Check the documentation for details.

Comment: How do you create a custom constructor? As far as I can tell Le, Ke, and Ge are not standard constructors?